# Can't create a dynamic page

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $resulta ))  { 
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['denumire_locatie']}</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['tip_locatie']}</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['judet']}</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['localitate']}</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['strada']}</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['numar']}</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['telefon']}</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['fax']}</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['email']}</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['descriere']}</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td><a href="/oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}">click pentru detalii</a></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>";   
}
```

When I run I get the following error message:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SITE\index.php on line 157
Line 157 is the following one:

```
echo "\t\t<td><a href="/oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}">click pentru detalii</a></td>\n";
```

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: You use double quotes, should be single quotes: '/oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use double quotes wrapped by double quotes...when you get this situation either alternate single and double quotes or escape the inner quotes with `\`  like `\"`.

> But escaping is the better choice in IMHO, when you want to maintain
>   consistency while writing the attributes of `html` tags.

Either:

```
 echo "\t\t<td><a href=\"/oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}\">click pentru detalii</a></td>\n";
```

Or

```
echo "\t\t<td><a href='/oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}'>click pentru detalii</a></td>\n";
```

Changed code:

```
<?php while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $resulta )) 
                     { 
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['denumire_locatie']}</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['tip_locatie']}</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['judet']}</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['localitate']}</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['strada']}</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['numar']}</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['telefon']}</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['fax']}</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['email']}</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t<td>{$result['descriere']}</td>\n";
                        echo "\t\t<td><a href=\"/oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}\">click pentru detalii</a></td>\n";
                        echo "</tr>";   
                     } 
                     echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line the double quotes end your echo string.

```
echo "\t\t<td><a href="/oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}">click pentru detalii</a></td>\n";
                      ^
```

To avoid (escape) this behavior put a backslash infront of it

```
echo "\t\t<td><a href=\"/oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}\">click pentru detalii</a></td>\n";
                      ^                                      ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "\t\t<td><a href="
                      ^ end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace with:

```
echo "\t\t<td><a href=\"/oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}\">click pentru detalii</a></td>\n";
```

You have to escape the " as you use it as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo "\t\t<td><a href=\"/oferta.php?id={$result['id_oferta']}\">click pentru detalii</a></td>\n";
```

You have to escape your " so PHP won't get confused... .